# React, how to do an include on an array within an axios requested object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, include, axios

I'm doing a project where I have an Item that can have multiple categories. The category ids are stored in the item object as an array. I want to be able to be able to display the category names.

in the code below I attempt to get the categories (cats) from my backend. Than use a filter method with a include parameter to retrieve the desired objects from.

However, I get a "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined" error, on the line where I attempt this.state.prod.cat.includes(cats.id).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class items extends Component {
    state = {
        item: {},
        cats: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:5001/items/5d722a4e630c27623003dfcb")
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ item: response.data });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        axios
            .get("http://localhost:5001/cats")
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    cats: response.data.filter(cats =>
                        this.state.item.cat.includes(cats.id)
                    )
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.cats.map(({ _id, name }) => (
                    <Link exact to={"/category/" + _id}>
                        <span>{name}</span>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default items;
```

Comment: Hi Sean, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because, component first render's with initial state. Initially you have `item: {}`, so when yo do `this.state.item.cat.includes(cats.id)` it gives you the error.

I think you should not call API in render method.

`componentDidMount` is the best place to call your API.

You can make use of callback in setState for your API call,

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:5001/items/5d722a4e630c27623003dfcb")
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({ 
           item: response.data 
        }, () => {   //Call your API here
            axios
              .get("http://localhost:5001/cats")
              .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                  cats: response.data.filter(cats =>
                    this.state.item.cat.includes(cats.id)
                  )
                });
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use componentDidMount for calling your api.
componentDidMount will fetch data from api after that render function get call.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class items extends Component {
    state = {
        item: {},
        cats: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
         .get("http://localhost:5001/items/5d722a4e630c27623003dfcb")
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ item: response.data });
            })
            .then(()=>{
                   axios
            .get("http://localhost:5001/cats")
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    cats: response.data.filter(cats =>
                        this.state.item.cat.includes(cats.id)
                    )
                });
            })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.cats.map(({ _id, name }) => (
                    <Link exact to={"/category/" + _id}>
                        <span>{name}</span>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Render() is highly discouraged to be used for side effects (API calls). Move the code to ComponentdidMount. 
Render functions get a call every time state changes so it's definitely not a good idea to make an API call in Render. 
**TIP:** Use useEffect in functional components for API calls.

Here is how to do it

```
 componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:5001/cats')
  .then((res) => {
    // do something with cat Res

    return axios.get('http://localhost:5001/items/5d722a4e630c27623003dfcb');
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // do something with items res
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle err
  });
```

An Alternative

```
 componentDidMount() {

  axios.all([
    axios.get('http://localhost:5001/cats'),
    axios.get('http://localhost:5001/items/5d722a4e630c27623003dfcb')
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((cats, items) => {
    // do something with both responses
  }));

    }
```